# Are there a better method to make this effect? [CUSTOM BOTTOMBAR]

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to make my first app with Flutter.
I have a question i make this custom bottom bar: 
Are there better method for make this effect or similar effect? 
Is it correct this method with stack and row? 
Thanks u and good coding!

```
Container bottom(Size size) {
    double totalElement = size.width / 3;
    return Container(
      height: size.width * 0.15,
      //color: GS.mainColor,
      child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
        children: [
          //LONG ELEMENT 
          Positioned(
            child: Container(
              width: totalElement*3,
              height: GS.heightBottomElement,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.green,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topRight: Radius.circular(20),
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                )
              ),
            )
          ),
          //FIRST ELEMENT
          Positioned(
            child: Container(
              height: GS.heightBottomElement,
              width: totalElement*2,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topRight: Radius.circular(20),
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                )
              ),
            )
          ),
          //FIRST ELEMENT
          Positioned(
            child: Container(
              height: GS.heightBottomElement,
              width: totalElement,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.orange,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topRight: Radius.circular(20),
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                )
              ),
            )
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could extract the Positioned elements into a separate stateless widget, in that way you use the [DRY method](https://www.google.com/search?q=DRY%20method%2C&rlz=1C1BYYL_svSE931SE931&oq=DRY%20method%2C&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), and your code will look nicer and cleaner, with less repeated code.

It would look like this:

```
Container bottom(Size size) {
double totalElement = size.width / 3;
return Container(
  height: size.width * 0.15,
  //color: GS.mainColor,
  child: Stack(
    alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
    children: [
      //LONG ELEMENT 
      MyCutomPositioned(height: blabla, width: blabla, color: blabla),
      //FIRST ELEMENT
      MyCutomPositioned(height: blabla, width: blabla, color: blabla),
      //SECOND ELEMENT
      MyCutomPositioned(height: blabla, width: blabla, color: blabla),
    ],
  ),
);
```

}